# When to take three steps forward

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish, hefsek-interruption

Before beginning Shemoneh Esrei, one takes three steps forward. Should they be taken after the kaddish beforehand is completed, to avoid being *mafsik* with the Amen? Or should you begin the steps while kaddish is in progress, so you can start Shemoneh Esrei without delay?

Similarly, what should one do by Shacharis? Should you finish *ga'al yisrael* before starting the steps or not?

Comment: I heard/read you should not move while making a braha - so for Shacharis you should certainly finish _gaal Israel_ before starting the steps. For Shemoneh Esrei it is important all start together - so see what others do - in case of doubt I'd do like the hazan

Answer (score 2):

I personally witnessed Rav Avigdor Nevenzahl shlit"a during shacharis would take his three steps before he finished גאל ישראל as a הידור of סמוך גאולה לתפילה - that the blessing of redemption should be close to the prayer.

He did this as well for Maariv. He takes his three steps as the tzibbur is saying the final of Amen of קדיש.